# PHP Time frame, get total hours, evening hours, night hours, weekend hours and holidays

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm currently working on an application and i need to add a new function to its existing invoicing system.

Employees give up their working hours like the following:

```
Start: 18:30 01-01-2012
End: 00:30 02-01-2012
```

Now when someone creates an invoice from a chosen date range, the system generated the total worked hours x hourly price. This works fine and is not the problem.

Now the system needs to be able to charge extra % on top of the hourly rate if the worked time is for example in the evening, night, weekend (saturday/sunday) and on holidays.

Does anybody has any idea how to realise this?

To get the weekends is not that difficult but when i get the weekends i also need to find out how many hours are worked in these weekends.. its kinda multidimensional...

My idea was to first loop through the time range, first loop the dates per day and then loop the hours of each day and then make some sort of check in each loop to check if it are night hours, eveninghours.. weekendhours.. holiday hours..

I would love to hear any idea's since im kinda stuck..

Answer (score 0):

I have already found a solution to do what i want. So i would like to share it for anyone else who has to make the same sort of thing.

I have created a loop between the start datetime and end datetime with an interval of 15 minutes, since the employees always start or end at an exact hour or :15, :30, :45.

On every 15 minute interval i checked if the date falls into a holiday, eveninghour, nighthour or weekendhour (saturday + sunday).

I have added the holidays date into an array, same as the eveninghours and nighthours.

On each IF statement check i made a counter to keep track of the 15 minutes for each type, holidays, eveninghour, nighthours or weekend.

So at the end you have the totalminutes for each type of hour or holiday or weekend, this divided by 60 gives you the total hours worked in each type of hour, holiday or weekend. And based on that i calculated the extra fee to be charged if worked on those hours.

I'ts maybe not the best approach, but it worked for me.